# How can I set a proxy with authentication (username & password) on the webbrowser control in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, proxy

I'm already using InternetSetOption and wininet to change the proxy settings for Internet Explorer which works since the webbrowser control uses it too, but how can I add it so that it can use authentication-required proxies (user:pass)?
Here's my code:

```
Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure


Private Sub setProxy(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

    Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

    Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
End Sub
Private Declare Auto Function InternetSetOption Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
```

And this is what I use whenever I want to change the proxy:

```
setProxy("ip:port")
```

So how can I add support for authentication?