# WebBrowser how to use private proxy with id:pass

Tags: .net, vb.net, proxy

So basically i've got this code made from bits and pieces, and i use it as an event listener when WebBrowser1.navigating is triggered so it will use the proxy on every navigation, no exception.

The only problem is that i don't know how to modify the code to use a private proxy based on id:pass

```
#Region "Using Proxy"
<Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("wininet.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function InternetSetOption(ByVal hInternet As IntPtr, ByVal dwOption As Integer, ByVal lpBuffer As IntPtr, ByVal lpdwBufferLength As Integer) As Boolean
End Function

Public Structure Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO
    Public dwAccessType As Integer
    Public proxy As IntPtr
    Public proxyBypass As IntPtr
End Structure

Private Sub UseProxy(ByVal strProxy As String)
    Const INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY As Integer = 38
    Const INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY As Integer = 3

    Dim struct_IPI As Struct_INTERNET_PROXY_INFO

    struct_IPI.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY
    struct_IPI.proxy = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi(strProxy)
    struct_IPI.proxyBypass = Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi("local")

    Dim intptrStruct As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))

    Marshal.StructureToPtr(struct_IPI, intptrStruct, True)

    Dim iReturn As Boolean = InternetSetOption(IntPtr.Zero, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, intptrStruct, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(struct_IPI))
End Sub
#End Region
```

This is the code snippet i'm using wherever i need it:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_Navigating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles WebBrowser1.Navigating
    UseProxy(TextBox3.Text & ":" & TextBox4.Text)
End Sub
```

I'm sure that the solution to this is abysmally simple, just that it's avoiding my mad VB skills!

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23767475/how-can-i-set-a-proxy-with-authentication-username-password-on-the-webbrowse

Comment: and again http://www.blackhatworld.com/blackhat-seo/visual-basic-net/385225-vbulletin-help-needed-proxies.html

Comment: best answer I have found http://stackoverflow.com/a/300738/2319909

Comment: more info http://sticklebackplastic.com/post/2007/01/26/Poxy-proxies.aspx

Comment: Aw damn, i'm so sorry for my ignorance, it won't happen again! i'll proceed to the links ASAP. Thanks for posting them, and sorry again :(

Comment: No problem - took me a while to find the actual code to solve the problem (see answer below!)  Seems like lots of peopole have had the same issue before.  Google is your friend!

Answer (score 0):

This KB article explains how to implement authentication with wininet library

[How To Handle Proxy Authorization with WinInet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/195650)